# Can a Way of Astral Self Monk use wisdom related scores for jumping?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, monk, archetype

I have several questions on the interactions between the Arms of Astral Self and the Jumping mechanics.
According to the 3rd level feature, Arms of the Astral Self:

> While the spectral arms are present, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - You can use your **Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength modifier when making Strength checks and Strength saving throws**.
> - You can use the spectral arms to make unarmed strikes.
> - When you make an unarmed strike with the arms on your turn, your reach **for it is 5 feet greater than normal.**
> - The unarmed strikes you make with the arms can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength or Dexterity modifier for the attack and damage rolls, and their damage type is force.

The Jumping session of the PHB states:

> **Long Jump**

> When you make a long jump, you cover a number of feet up to your **Strength score** if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing long jump, you can leap only half that distance. Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.

> This rule assumes that the height of your jump doesn't matter, such as a jump across a stream or chasm. At your DM's option, you must succeed on a **DC 10 Strength (Athletics)** check to clear a low obstacle (no taller than a quarter of the jump's distance), such as a hedge or low wall. Otherwise, you hit it.

> **High Jump**

> When you make a high jump, you leap into the air a number of feet equal to **3 + your Strength modifier** (minimum of 0 feet) if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing high jump, you can jump only half that distance. Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement. In some circumstances, your DM might allow you to **make a Strength (Athletics) check** to jump higher than you normally can.

> You **can extend your arms half your height above yourself** during the jump. Thus, you can reach above you a distance equal to the height of the jump plus 1½ times your height.

My questions would be, assuming that I have Arms of the Astral Self activated:

1. Can I use my Wisdom Score instead of my Strength score to determine my long jump distance?
2. Can I make a Wisdom (Athletics) check instead of a Strength (Athletics) check?
3. Can I use my Wisdom modifier instead of my Strength modifier to determine my high jump's height?
4. Can the extra 5 feet range of the Arms of Astral Self be used when accounting for "extending your arms half your height above yourself" on the high jump, making it 1½ your height + 5 feet  instead of only 1½ your height?

I am aware that some of the answers to these questions are up to DM discretion, so I would like to know, if possible, what would be the RAW interpretation and also how would you rule it in your games.

In advance, I'm extremely grateful to whoever takes time to answer these :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Multiple answers; based on RAW/RAI

> Can I use my Wisdom Score instead of my strength score to determine my long jump distance?

No, the feature states you can use Wisdom, "when making Strength checks and Strength saving throws". This is neither. Instead, it is just looking for the modifier as a straight value.

> Can I make a Wisdom (Athletics) check instead of a Strength (Athletics) check?

Yes, this is exactly what the feature is for.

> Can I use my Wisdom modifier instead of my Strength modifier to determine my high jump's height?

Same as the first question, this is not a Skill check or saving throw so the feature does not apply.

> Can the extra 5 feet range of the Arms of Astral Self be used when accounting for "extending your arms half your height above yourself" on the high jump, making it 1½ your height + 5 feet instead of only 1½ your height?

This is a lot of DM fiat. The feature is pretty specific, "**When you make an unarmed strike...**" you get 5 extra feet of reach. ["Reach"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) is a term used in combat so it has a specific application. I cannot find any rules regarding reach being used for anything outside of combat; generally the rules say "Range" which is very different.

But it wouldn't be outside the realm of possibility for a DM to say that during the jump the monk would "strike out" at the ledge to grab something out of normal range.

As a DM I would "Rule of Cool" it and allow extra range to grab a ledge. But I would say "no" for question #1 and #3, and "yes" for making Wisdom (Athletics) checks.

Comment: In your first paragraph you note that the feature explicitly lets you use Wisdom in place of Strength for ability checks; but then in your second you suggest you'd have to get DM fiat to use Wisdom for Athletics checks.  Doesn't the part of the feature that you reference give you the inherent ability to use Wisdom for Athletics checks, RAW?

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle, you're correct. I've update my answer

Answer (score 6):

Question #2 (Can I make a Wisdom (Athletics) check instead of a Strength (Athletics) check?) is clearly "yes", RAW.

The other three are not specifically stated in the Arms of the Astral Self feature, and thus RAW are not the case.  #1 (Can I use my Wisdom Score instead of my strength score to determine my long jump distance?) and #3 (Can I use my Wisdom modifier instead of my Strength modifier to determine my high jump's height?) are arguable, and definitely DM discretion.  #4 (Can the extra 5 feet range of the Arms of Astral Self be used when accounting for "extending your arms half your height above yourself" on the high jump, making it 1½ your height + 5 feet instead of only 1½ your height?) is fairly clearly a "no", RAW, as it only applies to unarmed strikes.

As a DM, I would definitely say "yes" to #1 and #3, and probably give #4 a "yes" as well, as "rule of cool".